# Error when Committing in SVN using subclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, commit, subclipse

> "org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E155007:
>   'C:\User\Bosung\Workspace\Chicken
>   Survival.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs' is not a working copy"

Details is same.

I have this problem when I try to commit to **SVN** for the past few days and I have no idea how to fix.
I believe this problem occurred after installing **Egit** but I am not quite sure.

- I tried to going back in installation history but this gives me error.
- I tried deleting egit, and subclipse and reinstalling subclipse in "installed software" tab but the same problem still exists.
- I tried to delete and make a new java project (by copying only the classes I need back into the new project) but same problem still exists.

I am using Version: **Indigo Service Release 2 Build id: 20120216-1857**
SVN is hosted on **projectlocker.com**

Help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What happened? Couldn't your project get committed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error description says it: ***your file is not a working copy***. When you commit your project, a Window with all the folders/files to commit will appear. Just uncheck the folder `.settings` and accept the commit.

Comment: I tried creating a brand new java project with nothing inside.
then I right click chicken survival project -> team -> share project
then same error pops up.
It seems like my whole eclipse is messed up.... SIGH!!! 
i will reinstall eclipse I guess.........

Comment: I fixed the problem by creating a new workspace.! now I can finally work on my project again.!! sigh~!!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this every time I saved a file in a new directory/package. I added the directory to svn and it seems to have fixed it.